# Emulator: cannot find ram.img on ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, ubuntu-18.04, nexus-5x

I simply set up a Nexus 5x device with API 27 in the default emulator in Android Studio 3.5.
When I was trying to boot the device, the device just closed after the first 'Google' sign.
The event log there's the following output:

```
Emulator: statvfs('/home/qiufeng/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img') failed: No such file or directory

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

However, the ram.img exists. I also changed the permission of the whole directory and files and It didn't work.

I've tried cold booting it... And that broke my deepin os--Deepin OS now fails to load the linux kernel:-(
The method, which I found on the Internet, saying to Open device settings and turn Emulator Performance's section from Automatic to 'Software'. However, the section is not enabled and it doesn't let me set the value.

Is there a method to solve the problem and let the device start properly?:-)

Comment: I have the same problem as you with Ubuntu 18.04, did you manage to work something out?

Comment: I just checked that KVM is working OK, so I reinstalled everything without success, I'm reading the same error messages :(

Comment: It seems there are more people having this problem lately. It occurs to me that it's a new bug, happening perhaps only in Android Studio 3.5 or maybe in a recent version of the Android Tools. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859172/error-starting-android-emulators-on-ubuntu-18

Comment: I reported the bug some days ago, maybe you can add more info https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141255618